# Can I use a heredoc to enter a password in bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, heredoc

I know about RSA authentication, but for my purposes I want to use a heredoc to specify the password.  I want something like the following, but I can't get it to work.  Is this even possible?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter Password: "
read -s password
ssh myhost << EOL
$password
echo "I'm logged onto myhost"
EOL
echo done
```

This is what I get when I try it:

```
$ ./testssh 
Enter Password: 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user@myhost's password: 
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
mypassword: Command not found.
I'm logged onto myhost
done
```

EDIT:

Based on bmargulies' answer, I reworked my script and came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the Host: "
read HOST
echo -n "Enter Username: "
read USER
echo -n "Enter Password: "
read -s PASS
VAR=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh $USER@$HOST
expect \"password:\"
send \"$PASS\r\"
expect \">\"
send \"ls\r\"
send \"echo 'I\'m on $HOST'\r\"
expect -re \"stuff\"
send \"logout\"
")
echo -e "\n\n\n========"
echo VAR = "$VAR"
echo done
```

Comment: Quote your variable to preserve newlines: `echo VAR = "$VAR"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programs that read passwords often specifically open /dev/tty to defeat redirection. In which case, the tool you need is 'expect', which will run one behind a pseudo-tty.

Comment: @B Johnson it has been, literally, years since I used expect. I see that Dennis helped you with the details.

Comment: Keep in mind that Expect is a general-purpose language which can do everything bash does, and arguably more easily.  Those of us who chose to write Expect scripts, as opposed to Expect-embedded-uncomfortably-in-bash, avoid a lot of the "quoting hell" evident in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

If you mix in w/ perl, you can do something "clean" (from a non needing to quote view) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="ssh myhost << EOL"
echo -n "Enter Password: "
read -s password
# answer password prompt
#   note we use ctl-A as our quote delimeter around the password so we run
#   no risk of it escaping quotes
script='
use Expect;
use ysecure;
my $exp = new Expect;
$exp->raw_pty(1);
$exp->spawn(q|<CMD>|);
$exp->expect(30,">");
$exp->send(q^A<PASSWORD>^A . "\n");
$exp->soft_close();
$exp->exitstatus() && die;
'

script=${script//<CMD>/$cmd}
script=${script//<PASSWORD>/$password}

perl -e "$script"
```