# How to enter ssh password using bash?

Tags: bash, ssh

Everyday I am connecting to a server through ssh. I go through this routine:

```
IC001:Desktop user$ ssh user@my.server.com
user@my.server.com's password: 

Last login: Tue Jun  4 10:09:01 2013 from 0.0.0.0
$
```

I would like to automate this process and create a bash script to do it for me. I don't care about security and okay to store my password openly in the script. I am also okay for it to get typed openly on the screen while the script gets executed. So I've created this:

```
#!/bin/bash          
ssh user@my.server.com
echo mypassword
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried `send` instead of `echo`, but it also didn't work. Please advise if it is possible to do.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: @Kevin, I am not in charge of the servers. I am just a user which connects to them. I am not allowed to modify ANYTHING on the server.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298487/bash-script-to-ssh-into-a-machine-without-prompting-password-and-without-using-k?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796345/can-i-use-a-heredoc-to-enter-a-password-in-bash?rq=1

Comment: All you need to do on the server is add a single line to a configuration file in your home directory. If you can't do that, what can you do?

Comment: @Kevin, read logs... but that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Double check if you are not able to use keys.

Otherwise use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

Comment: uh...Is "assword" a typo or intended?

Comment: It is intended: It matches `Password` and `password`.

Comment: I tried this in TextExpander, but I get `spawn: command not found`. I tried it without the keyword, but nothing happens.

Comment: @jowie you should install `expect` with `sudo apt-get install expect` for example and then you'll have the spawn command

Comment: lol at the "uh..." comment

Comment: I always get my `asswords` mixed up

Comment: If Can't use expect, what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 96):

Create a new keypair: (go with the defaults)

```
ssh-keygen
```

Copy the public key to the server: (password for the last time)

```
ssh-copy-id user@my.server.com
```

From now on the server should recognize your key and not ask you for the password anymore:

```
ssh user@my.server.com
```

Comment: I am not allowed to do anything on the server. Is it possible to do it the other way?

Comment: What is the point of logging in, if you are not allowed to do anything there?

Comment: to read the logs only... but that's not the point.

Comment: So the point is that you have very limited access to a server whose admin has locked down security and you want to leave your password in plaintext on your machine because the server owner's security concerns are bothersome to you. Did I get that right? Why don't you ask that sysadmin how he feels about your script?

Comment: Needed to: ssh-agent bash && ssh-add   as shown here http://www.solomonson.com/content/setting-ssh-agent-ask-passphrase-only-once  to get this to work.

Comment: Oh snap! lmao @Prostak. I go to great lengths to distill my questions down to the bare minimum so that answerers/commenters don't get their panties in a bunch about things that have nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: If you're on OSX or another OS that doesn't have `ssh-copy-id` then there are one-line alternatives [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/188/copy-your-ssh-public-key-to-a-server-from-a-machine-that-doesnt-have-ssh-copy-id).

Comment: Will not work in all type of devices. Some devices are router and not Linux

Comment: You can do [key based authentication](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/sec_user_services/configuration/guide/15_1/sec_user_services_15_1_book/sec_secure_shell_v2.html#wp1082784) for routers, too. But this would go beyond the scope of that question.

Comment: @Chev Also, `ssh-copy-id` is available from Homebrew.

Comment: @robert so simple ... so easy ! +1

Comment: If I sore my ssh key not in is_rsa which command I should use instead ssh-copy-id? Or it is the same so it will use the last generated key?

Comment: @fdrv Please read `man ssh-copy-id`. It will tell you about the `-i` option.

Comment: @Chev ssh-copy-id is on macOS (tested on Catalina)