# How to execute shell commands and interact with the output on linux using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, terminal

I use Eclipse and I try to execute `shell commands` written in a cpp-file.

As far as I know, I can use the `system()` function to execute a `shell command` in cpp, but how can I respond to a prompt in the terminal?

I know that after a certain command the shell will ask for a password and I have to put it in there. At first I tried to put my password into a second `system()` function but it didn't work. Although I put a `sleep` call between both `system()` function calls, it doesn't work:

```
system(DO)// after this command the shell asks for a password
sleep(10)
system(Password)`
```

How can I enter the password?

Comment: Is your application a terminal application? Or it's a graphical one?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the password in your first `system` instruction. If your command is something like `getPassword` then it will be:

```
system("echo yourPassword | getPassword");
```

Although including the plain password in the program is dangerous.

**UPDATE:**

For SSH it will not work, but for common commands that get arguments from console like `apt-get` it will work. Using [`sshpass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734873/777769) turns it back to getting password argument from stdin as normal.
Another alternative is [`expect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16928662/777769) in `Tcl` that can enter password for SSH automatically and conditional.

**Again, using plain text for password is not recommended at all. consider using public key authentication instead.**

Comment: Will not work for ssh - it takes passwords from console rather than stdin. "ps -ef" will show your password.