# Linux: Can't find expect in my /bin/ or /usr/bin after installing. How do I find it?

Tags: linux, bash

I realise this might be a stupid question, but I've been trying to follow the advice on the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928004/how-to-enter-ssh-password-using-bash

However, I've come up to a problem. I installed expect with `sudo apt-get install expect` but now embarrassingly I can't figure out where the script interpreter is. It doesn't seem to be in the normal paths where people look to (i.e `/bin/` or `/usr/bin/` ).

It does seem to have installed, since `$ expect` seems to work, but I just can't use the interpreter (i.e I try to shebang it like everyone else with `#!/bin/sh/expect` and it gives an error).

Comment: `which expect`?

Comment: @DusanBajic, better to suggest `type expect`; `which` doesn't know about aliases, functions, or otherwise anything but the PATH, so if the command the user is able to run interactively isn't coming from a binary in the PATH, `which` won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the location by listing all the files the package `expect` provides by `dpkg -L`:

```
dpkg -L expect
```

or narrow it down to only the filenames ending in `expect`:

```
dpkg -L expect | grep '/expect$'
```

or if resides in typical binary directories:

```
dpkg -L expect | grep -E '/s?bin/'
```

---

Also the typical way to go through the `$PATH` for an executable is to use:

```
which expect
```

or better (considering shell internals), not strictly needed in this case though:

```
type -a expect
```

Comment: ...I'd be curious as to whether anyone downvoting this could comment as to why -- it reads as spot-on to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
whereis expect
```

... (you could have guessed it ;)

Comment: `whereis`, like `which`, is an external command. Better to suggest `type`, which has the shell do its own lookup -- and will thus honor aliases, functions, etc -- and additionally avoids the startup overhead for running an external command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true, except it won't return the command/location when it is an alias.

Comment: sure, but `whereis` won't necessarily even tell you *what the external command is* that's actually being run when the user types `expect` at their prompt. Maybe they have `alias expect=expect1.1` defined; if the actual binary is something other than `expect`, then `whereis` is useless. (OTOH, if one *wants* to return only external commands, `type -P` will do that). And `type -a`, as suggested by heemayl, will return external commands *in addition to* aliases.