# SFTP connection using shell Script

Tags: unix

I am trying to run a shell script which is connecting to remote server through sftp. But each time its asking me to enter a password. Is there a way that I can do this automatic to pick up the password by itself ?

Comment: Expect - google it - it is a scripting language? Perhaps public/private key pair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter ssh password using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928004/how-to-enter-ssh-password-using-bash)