# Jupyter notebook password not working from SSH

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook

Trying to connect to a Jupyter Notebook through SSH.

I have a script which logs in to machine through SSH:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -L localhost:4000:localhost:8889 user@sshaddress.com
expect "assword:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

Set the jupyter password:

```
jupyter notebook password
# set it to something
```

Then I run jupyter:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Then I open my `localhost:4000` and get the jupyter login page.

However, putting in the password here only gives 'Invalid credentials'.

Why would this be?

Comment: Should `expect "assword:"` be `expect "password:"`?

Comment: No. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928004/how-to-enter-ssh-password-using-bash). Also, that's not related to the Jupyter stuff that's just for logging into the server with SSH.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, but I'm not sure if it's identical. I have two servers where I run notebooks which I access through SSH tunneling. Whether or not my password works depends on whether I use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in the URL. I cannot figure out why.

Case 1: Run browser on the server

- both localhost and 127.0.0.1 accept my password

Case 2: SSH to server 1

- localhost accepts my password
- 127.0.0.1 rejects my password

Case 3: SSH to server 2

- localhost rejects my password
- 127.0.0.1 accepts my password

If you access the server using 127.0.0.1:4000, does that work?